# Can't access internal lan router. OpenMptcpRouter

Tags: router

i have installed OpenMptcpRouter on a router Linksys WRT3200ACM. I have this setting:

Linksys ip 192.168.1.1 - Router1 ip 192.168.2.1 (dhcp) - Router2 ip 192.168.3.1 (dhcp)

The problem is if i'm connected to the Linksys and want to connect to router 1 (by typing 192.168.2.1 in the address bar) I don't have access to it!! Before upgrading to the latest version of OpenMptcpRouter everything was working. Can you help me?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the 'wrong' IP I suspect - you need to use the IP that the linksys supplies to router 1, 192.168.1.x.

There's ways around this, by setting specific routes for each range but this would be the 'right' way to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Good morning, thanks for the reply. For example I tried to set Router1 with ip 192.168.1.10 but it doesn't let me access...